# How do I accomplish following design using bootstrap 3.2.0?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to design something the first one in the picture below, there should not be left or right padding.

[image]

What I really want to do is:

- Two columns with background color. I've added two columns but bootstrap container and column classes adds padding and margins.
- Content inside those columns must be in normal paddings and margins.
- There must be no space / gutter between cols.
- It must be follow bootstrap's breaking points.

Comment: Posting image is not enough, you need to post your CODE and much better if you make a FIDDLE

Comment: If you're using the source files, find the variable in variables.less that specifies the gutter width and change it (if this is an issue you'll run into site-wide)

Comment: @Richa [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ejoo/myvxtazn/1/) is my fiddle:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in native Bootstrap to achieve this if you have two `<div>`s in the same `<row>`.  Just move your `left` and `right` classes into the same line as `col-xs-4` / `col-xs-8`.  Also you shouldn't have a `<section>` as a parent of your `<container>`, you should move it be a child of container (though I removed it below, since it seems unecessary).

Example:

```
<div class="container"> //change this to container-fluid if you want full screen width 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myvxtazn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a nopadding class like this one:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

If you add that class to your column divs there will be no padding on them.

Comment: You don't need to add this, the desired result is achievable with native bootstrap.

Comment: using `!important` css is the last thing if you can't use bootstrap features or normal css.